# How can I hand over a variable to a *char function?

Tags: c, function, char

I try to hand over this pointer `char *line;` using `rle_code(&line);` to this function:

```
char *rle_encode(char *line)
{

    return line;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: remove the `&`... Well, at least it will be correct type-wise.

Comment: Show an [MCVE] in your question. It has to have some `main`

Comment: What does it do or not do that it shouldn't do or should do?